# How do I remove the element with the word we want from the text I pulled from a website using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-search

I scraped 6 elements from a website with the Selenium find_element(By.XPATH) module and added these elements to a list.

I converted these elements into .text and search on google, but since the elements are changing, sometimes "UNKNOWN" may be written instead of elements and it prints "UNKNOWN".

When the elements are "UNKNOWN", I don't want it to list it, or if there is a method such as deletion, I can use that too.

```
birText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='collapse3']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/h3/strong")

ikiText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='collapse3']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/h3/strong")

ucText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='collapse3']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/h3/strong")


my_list = [birText.text,ikiText.text,ucText.text]
my_list = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
results = []

for query in my_list:
    results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=10, stop=10, pause=2))
for result in results: print(*list(result),sep='\n')
```

I hope I was able to explain
I want to print the .texts in the list that do not contain "UNKNOWN".

Comment: One solution is to use an `if` statement to avoid adding `'UNKNOWN'` to your list of results.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How can i do it?

Comment: Which variable or expression evaluates to `'UNKOWN'`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "UNKNOWN" is located in the xpath I scraped. Sometimes the website deletes the previously entered information and writes "UNKNOWN" instead.

Comment: Which variable in your code has the value `'UNKNOWN'`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice birText , ikiText, ucText These variables can give "UNKNOWN" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you need an `if` statement to decide whether or not to include an item in your array.

I would also add a `for` loop to remove some repetition:

```
def get_data(driver):
    for i in range(3):
        selector = f'//*[@id='collapse3']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[{i+1}]/div[1]/div/div/div/h3/strong'
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, selector)
        if element.text != 'UNKNOWN':
            yield element.text
```

With this function, you can now do

```
my_list = list(get_data(driver))
```

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='collapse3']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[0]/div[1]/div/div/div/h3/strong"}`

Comment: @aabb One way to fix this is to change the `{i}` to `{i + 1}`. I edited my answer to to this. Alternatively, you can modify the `range()` call to start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. It no longer lists "UNKNOWN" ones.
But when I add the code `print (birRole.text,":",birText.text)
print (ikiRole.text,":",ikiText.text)
print (ucRole.text,":",ucText.text)` , it prints 3 times from each print module. How can I fix this?

Comment: @aabb It is impossible to know what the problem is with such limited information. I suggest reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. If you still need help after debugging yourself, please post a new question with the current version of your code.